# How to represent infinity in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, infinity

I am writing a program that requires representing positive infinity some how in my code. Is there something like INTEGER_MAX in Racket?

Answer (score 4):

In `#lang racket` and other languages in the Racket family of languages you have floating point support and thus you have both infinities:

```
+inf.0
-inf.0
```

This is also true for the standard Scheme report languages implementations provided by Racket, like `#!r5rs`, and `#!r6rs`.

As for the Scheme standard only R6RS is required to support a full numeric tower. The latest [R7RS-small report (pdf, page 35)](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/r7rs.pdf)   states:

> The numbers positive infinity, negative infinity, and NaN are written
>   `+inf.0` , `-inf.0` and `+nan.0` respectively.  NaN may also be
>   written `-nan.0` . The use of signs in the written representation does
>   not necessarily reflect the underlying sign of the NaN value, if any. 
>   Implementations are not re- quired to support these numbers, but if
>   they do, they must do so in general conformance with IEEE 754. 
>   However, im- plementations are not required to support signaling NaNs,
>   nor to provide a way to distinguish between different NaNs.

Thus the stance is the same as for R5RS. The larger R7RS which is not comlpet yet might require a full numeric tower as it seems to have been up for debate.

Answer (score 1):

`+inf.0` seems to work for my purposes.